# Ruby on Rails 3 - Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resources, namespaces, routes

I am writing a rails application and getting stuck on a routing issue.

My application allows a user to manage multiple cause pages (for various reasons)

right now, I am trying to build the admin screens for users to update their site.

for example, cause pages could look like:

```
.com/causes/1
.com/causes/2
```

I and want the admin URL to be:

```
.com/causes/1/admin/updates
.com/causes/2/admin/updates
```

etc.

How would I setup my routes to do this

I originally thought something like:

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :updates
end
```

But how can I prefix that with the cause/:id so that I can relate which cause I am updating?

Comment: why not invert the routes to admin/causes/1/updates? that way you can have other admin tasks instead of adding admin to almost all your controllers

Comment: Yes, that makes sense..how would I set that up in my routes though?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have an admin_controller of sorts and you can setup your routes like so:

```
resources :admin do
  #insert any resource you need to have admin pages on here
  resources :causes do
    resources :updates do
    end
  end
end
```

something like that. Or you could try some rails admin gems to make your life easier like: http://www.activescaffold.com/